# Unable to access Api call data. Returns undefined. React

Tags: reactjs, themoviedb-api

I am trying to make a movie search app with React and have made an API call to The Movie Database API. What I am trying to do is get the data of the new movie releases, but then make another API call to get the specific details for each of those new releases since that data is stored in a different location.

I am able to access the data from the first API call, but when I try to access the movie taglines from the second data object, the console outputs "Cannot read property 'tagline' of undefined".

**App.js**

```
  class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        movieRows: [],
        ids: [],
        movieDetails: [],
      }
      this.performSearch = this.performSearch.bind(this);        
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.performSearch();
    }

    performSearch() {
      const urlString = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=6db3cd67e35336927891a72c05&language=en-US&page=1";
      axios.get(urlString)
        .then(res => {

          const results = res.data.results
          let movieRows = [];
          let movieDetails = [];

          results.forEach((movie) => {

            movieRows.push(movie);
            axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movie.id}?api_key=6db3cd67e35336927891a72c05&language=en-US`)
            .then(res => {
              movieDetails.push(res.data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
          });

          this.setState({
            movieRows: movieRows,
            movieDetails: movieDetails,
          });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });  
    }
```

**Content.js**

```
export default class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: 'Jonathan',
        }
        this.filmLoop = this.filmLoop.bind(this);
    }

    filmLoop() {

        let movieData = this.props.globalState.movieRows;
        let movieDetails = this.props.globalState.movieDetails;

        return movieData.map((movie, index) => {

            return (
                <div className="film" key={index}>
                    <img className="poster" src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342${movie.poster_path}`} alt="The Dark Knight poster" />
                    <div className="film-info">
                        <div className="film-title">
                            <h3>{movie.title}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <h4>{movieDetails[index].tagline}</h4>
```

*I get the error from the last line

Comment: your setState runs before movieDetails has been populated. This of course causes `movieDetails[index].tagline` to fail because there is nothing at that index.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the problem. Now how would I go about getting setState to run after movieDetails has been populated?

Comment: You could collect all the axios promises in an array then use promise.all to detect when they're all complete

Comment: Ok I'm going to try that.

Comment: After a couple hours of trying I got it working. Now I feel like I understand promises better. Thanks Kevin!

Answer (score 0):

Well the main issue is that you are calling `setState` outside your `.then` you have to update the state inside your `then` or your `catch`. This is because the `promise` is an `async` function, so you have to change the state only when the promise has been resolved of rejected.

```js
performSearch() {
      const urlString = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=6db3cd67e35336927891a72c05&language=en-US&page=1";
      axios.get(urlString)
        .then(responsePopular => {

          const results = responsePopular.data.results
          let movieRows = [];
          let movieDetails = [];

          results.forEach((movie) => {

            movieRows = [...movieRows, movie];

            axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movie.id}?api_key=6db3cd67e35336927891a72c05&language=en-US`)
            .then(responseMovie => {
              movieDetails = [...movieDetails, responseMovie.data];
              this.setState({
                movieRows: movieRows,
                movieDetails: movieDetails,  
              })

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
          });

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });  
    }
```

I think that this could solve your issue.